# How to create list of random int and set it as value using @property decorator in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am fairly new to the concept of decorators.

I am trying to implement a function which creates a list of random integers and set it to the `group_list` variable in the `__init__` method.

And the second method takes an input from the user and set it to the `value` variable in the `__init__` method.

```
class Order(object):

def __init__(self, group_list=None, value=None):
    self.group_list=groupList
    self.value=number
    print(self.groupList)


@property
def groupList(self):
    return self._groupList

@groupList.setter
def _groupList(self):
    global list_val
    for _ in range(10):
        currentelement= randint(1,15)
        list_val.append(currentelement)
    self._groupList=list(set(list_val))

@property
def number(self):
    return self._number

@number.setter
def number(self):
    val=input('Enter any number from the list: ')
    self._number=val
```

What am I doing wrong here ? Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: What error are you getting? What output are you expecting from your tests vs which output are you getting?

Comment: It says ‘Order has no attribute groupList’

Comment: I am expecting groupList to return a list of randomly generated integers.

Comment: Please provide example code of how you are instantiating the object and what you're doing that is generating the errors. Also please provide the error output as a code block. You can just edit your question to add these items. There are several errors in this code, but I'd like to get your instantiation, attempted use, and error information so I can produce a complete answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what it's like to try to accomplish a task on limited time, and have to wait for answers to questions, so I took really big swing at your problem while I had some down time today. I hope overall I managed to answer your question (What am I doing wrong here ?).

Forgive me for not detailing everything out in sections bouncing in and out of code blocks, I was in a bit of a hurry. In addition, with all commenting done within the code, you can copy/paste this into a file, and run it. This assumes python3+

```
from random import randint

class Order(object):

    # Notice that group_list is used several places, so in the parameters I'm changing it to g_list just to make
    # it obvious which variable or parameter is being accessed
    def __init__(self, g_list=None, value=None):
        # Whenever calling a method inside of class, you have to reference the class
        # itself as part of the call. So in this case the call should be `self.groupList`
        #
        # Pep8 calls for methods to be lower case rather than hump case, and when using python
        # getter/setter (properties) you usually want to set a property with a different name (implied private) than
        # the defined property (getter/setter).
        #
        # Notice a few things in the new call. The property name is made private, and the methods that are decorated
        # with @property and @method.setter are NOT private or protected (see below). Also note that since
        # We're calling the group_list property below we need to set a value (notice the list_val property
        # in the setter below).
        #
        #
        # NOTE: If we were to set the __group_list directly, we would not allow any of the code in the setter
        # method to execute, possibly bypassing any data checking we wanted to do.
        #
        # self.group_list=groupList becomes:
        self.__group_list = []  # defines the property we're going to use
        self.group_list = g_list # calls the setter passing in the g_list parameter

        # Again since you are accessing your properties with methods, make the value private or at least protected
        # keep in mind that python's idea of private and protected methods is strictly a suggestion. There really
        # isn't a private/protected method in python.
        #
        # Since at this point we're assuming a "value" was passed into the class, we can't call the
        # setter, or it will ask for a number right away. If that's the goal, there are better ways to handle it.
        # with the information provided in the question, it's best to just set this value directly. Of course you
        # should verify the data first.
        #
        # self.__value=self.number
        self.__value = value

        # removed so not to cause confusion with example code outside object
        # print(self.group_list)


    @property
    # Here the method is named according to what we want to access in our code. Also properly
    # named using word_word format. The property decorator tells python to treat this as a
    # getter, and return a value. In this case we're returning the value of the property we created in init.
    #
    # def groupList(self):
    def group_list(self):
        # here we change the name of the property to be returned to match the property we defined in the init
        # return self._groupList
        return self.__group_list

    # The name of the property setter decorated must match the name of a method defined by the property
    # decorator prior to the setter being defined.
    #
    # @groupList.setter
    @group_list.setter
    # The method name must match the method name used where you defined the property as mentioned above. Also
    # notice that I added a parameter so that the list_val can be passed into the method.
    # def _groupList(self):
    #
    # Please note that if you're not going to need to use the parameter on a "setter" you're better off
    # not using the setter decorator and just renaming the method to something logical. In this case, something
    # like "generate_list" would be perfect.
    def group_list(self, list_val):
        # Global values in python are global only to the module. Your code as I was typing this did not include any
        # declaration of the list_val, and even if you have one defined, you should still pass in the value
        # and more than likely do away with a global defined one.
        #
        # There is a place for module level variables of course, but they should be the exception not the rule when
        # working with objects. Your code is much clearer, and is likely no less efficient by passing around references
        # of lists.
        #
        # global list_val
        if list_val is None:
            for _ in range(10):
                # You can do all of this in a single line. Notice though that I changed
                # the property being set.
                # currentelement= randint(1,15)
                # list_val.append(currentelement)
                # self._groupList=list(set(list_val))
                self.__group_list.append(randint(1, 15))
        elif isinstance(list_val, list):
            self.__group_list = list_val

    @property
    def number(self):
        # here again, we want to access the property we are setting.
        #
        # return self._number
        return self.__value

    # Setters require a signature of (self, value). You have a signature of (self) here. A setter is expecting
    # that you will want to pass a value in to be set.
    #
    # Without knowing all the details involved I have to say that this code produces smell. It would likely be
    # better to ask for the user input someplace else in your code and pass that value in to be stored or do something
    # with it. Having a module or class devoted to user interaction (a View) is common. But having it mixed with
    # application logic is usually bad.
    #
    # assuming you want to keep this request within the class here, this would be best renamed and not used
    # as a setter.
    #
    # Again notice the change from _number to __value.
    #
    # Also note I added a conversation to integer on the user input. This assumes the user will always chose an
    # integer. Of course checks should be put in place to validate all user input.
    #
    # @number.setter
    # def number(self):
    #     val=input('Enter any number from the list: ')
    #     self._number=val
    def ask_user_for_number(self):
        val=input('Enter any number from the list: ')
        self.__value=int(val)


# now I can use the class as such:

# If I pass no data in at instantiation a new list will be
print("Example with random list")
obj = Order()
obj.ask_user_for_number()
print("List of numbers: {}".format(obj.group_list))
print("User selected: {}".format(obj.number))
in_list = obj.number in obj.group_list
print(in_list)

# if I want to provide a list
print("-" * 10)
print("Example with fixed list")
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
my_obj = Order(g_list=my_list)
my_obj.ask_user_for_number()
print("List of numbers: {}".format(my_obj.group_list))
print("User selected: {}".format(my_obj.number))
in_my_list = my_obj.number in my_obj.group_list
print(in_my_list)
```

Comment: hey! The output is exactly what i needed. Thank you so much for taking out time  and making my problem, your own problem, and finally coming up with a solution with all the explanations! It means a lot!